# Mod_Perl Install Error

Tags: redhat, rhel5, mod-perl

I am installing software and one of the dependencies is mod_perl, when i run

```
  #perl Makefile.PL
```

I receive this error:

************* WARNING *************

Your Perl is configured to link against libgdbm,

but libgdbm.so was not found.

You could just symlink it to /usr/lib/libgdbm.so.2.0.0

EDIT:  I am using RHEL 5

HELP me???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into this issue awhile back, check to see if libgdbm is installed, if it is do the following to ensure its linked correctly:

Just noticed you said you were using RHEL5 same system I was using so these should work perfectly for you

`ls -l /usr/lib/libgdbm.so*`

It may look similar to this:

```
/usr/lib/libgdbm.so.2 -> libgdbm.so.2.0.0
/usr/lib/libgdbm.so.2.0.0
```

If so you can run this command to symlink

```
cd /usr/lib
ln -s libgdbm.so.2.0.0 libgdbm.so
```

Then run the command again:

```
ls -l /usr/lib/libgdbm.so*
```

should look something like this:

```
/usr/lib/libgdbm.so -> libgdbm.so.2.0.0
/usr/lib/libgdbm.so.2 -> libgdbm.so.2.0.0
/usr/lib/libgdbm.so.2.0.0
```

Try to install again

Comment: Your welcome! I just did this about two weeks ago

Answer (score 1):

It's more helpful to give an idea of what kind of system you're talking about.

Just for grins, I'm going to guess Ubuntu Linux.

You could do exactly what it says: read the manpage for ln(1) for more details on symlinks, but:

```
 ln -s /usr/lib/libgdbm.so.2.0.0 /usr/lib/lbgdbm.so
```

might just fix your problem.

It might not, because there are so many other things that could affect this and you have not narrowed down the field much for us.

I would suspect that a better approach would be to use your system's native package manager, if my guess at ubuntu is correct, I think you want:

```
apt-get install libapache2-mod-perl2
```

If the native package manager approach won't work for you, even more reason why you need to give more information and write a better question.